# Is there a way to automatically format spaces in Atom to make neat columns?

Tags: formatting, latex, atom-editor

Basically, I'd like to go from this

```
@inproceedings{208512,
    author = {Phillip Rogaway},
    title = {The Moral Character of Cryptographic Work},
    year = {2016},
    address = {Austin, TX},
    publisher = {{USENIX} Association},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 25th {USENIX} Security Symposium ({USENIX} Security 16)},
    month = {August}
}
```

to this

```
@inproceedings{208512,
    author      = {Phillip Rogaway},
    title       = {The Moral Character of Cryptographic Work},
    year        = {2016},
    address     = {Austin, TX},
    publisher   = {{USENIX} Association},
    booktitle   = {Proceedings of the 25th {USENIX} Security Symposium ({USENIX} Security 16)},
    month       = {August}
}
```

I've tried various things in the regex Find/Replace function of Atom, but I don't know if there's a way to do what I'm looking for. I was thinking I could specify a row location (like *x* characters in), and fill the space between `[a-z]*` and `=` with spaces... but I haven't seen anything online to suggest I *could* do that.

Any help (even to tell me it's impossible in Atom, or suggest another tool) would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question shows no evidence of research or  effort. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Atom has multiple packages that allow you to align in various ways. 
Open your preferences, click `+ Install` and enter "align", browse through them, and try a few to see what you like.